# How to pass diff parameters dynamically for a function using backbone js?

Tags: html, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Here is the fiddle i was playing with

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c44f5/)

this is my html

```
<div id="search_container">a</div>
<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
    <label>Search</label>
    <input type="text" id="search_input" />
    <input type="button" class="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
     <input type="button" class="button" id="a" value="asfasd" />
     <input type="button" class="button" id="b" value="Seaasdasdrch" />
     <input type="button" class="button" id="c" value="Seadasdasdasrch" />
</script>
```

and this is my Javascript

```
 SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        // Compile the template using underscore
        var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        this.$el.html( template );
    },
    events: {
        "click input[class=button]": "doSearch"  
    },
    doSearch: function( event ){
        // Button clicked, you can access the element that was clicked with event.currentTarget
       alert( "Search for " + $("#a").val() );
    }
});
    
var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
```

I want to call a same function for a bunch of buttons, but I want to give different parameters for them depending upon their values.
It takes the value of first element as value; how do I overcome and give unique attribute to different buttons?

Please help me out .. !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get your question properly, I think you want to capture the different values of the following buttons

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
<input type="button" class="button" id="a" value="asfasd" />
<input type="button" class="button" id="b" value="Seaasdasdrch" />
<input type="button" class="button" id="c" value="Seadasdasdasrch" />
```

If so, you can modify your code to the following:

```
doSearch: function( event ){
    // Button clicked, you can access the element that was clicked with event.currentTarget
    alert( "Search for " + $(event.currentTarget).attr('value') );
}
```